SaveChangesAsync throws but actually the changes were saved
I am using EF Core version 8.0.8 with SQL Server database. Due to recent problems in our IT infrastructure, the database is running slower than usual and we often run into query timeouts. We observed that sometimes when we call SaveChangesAsync on the DbContext, the call fails with a timeout exception. However, when inspecting the database tables, it seems that all changes were actually saved correctly.
Is this a bug, maybe in the database or in EF? I always thought that no changes are made in the database when SaveChangesAsync throws an exception.
Or is this the correct behavior and as intended by the EF developers?
Note: This is the exception:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.


You can address this by increasing the timeout, adding retry logic, or managing transactions.
context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

I understand that increasing the timeouts and retries may help with connection problems. However, is it possible that SaveChangesAsync throws (because of timeout) and changes are still saved in the DB? If this is the case, I dont know how I should implement a retry, because I dont know whether the changes were actually saved or not.

Can you share the exception? is it an SqlException?

I added the exception in the description.

If you want all change to happen at once or not at all, you need to use transaction and commit it by yourself. If you have, for example, multiple SQL statements pending (modifying the data), so every operation is immediately committed. If it fails along the way, all changes took place already.

I am just speculating here, but a timeout is caused by the client, and I think it's possible that the timeout message could reach the server when the server has already finished the update. In which case I believe it won't rollback. Https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810786/what

Especially if it's a network issue, the server could have easily finished it's work and be attempted to return the result and the timeout command could be also held up in the network at the same time. It's not going to rollback a command it's already completed AFAIK

@MichałTurczyn According to the docs, EF already uses a transaction when saving changes. This is confirmed by the stacktrace, which contains, for example, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Commit.

But who commits them? You don't have control over that, so they are maybe committed.

@DaleK Thank you, this is an interesting read and it would explain the observed behavior.

Maybe the commit is sent and the timeout occurs on the callback back to the client. That's the only way it could be saved in my opinion, otherwise something is not correct in the transaction handling

Is the SaveChanges method overridden in your code?

@AlexanderPetrov No, it is not.
